# Visual Studio 2022 opens "How do you want to open this file" when running dotnet commands from Developer Powershell

Tags: visual-studio-2022, dotnet-cli

Executing dotnet commands in Developer Powershell or terminals within the Visual Studio 2022 IDE throws up a "How would you like to open this file" dialog rather than executing the dotnet command.

I have Visual Studio 2022 installed and the dotnet 3 and 7 sdks.
I can execute dotnet commands in a new command window
e.g.

[image]

but when I try the same commands in the Developer Powershell  window or terminal within Visual Studio I get a dialog asking "How would you like to open this file" instead of the command being executed:
[image]

Any ideas on how to correct this?

Answer (score 2):

I've worked this out.  For some reason, there was a dotnet file in my C:\Windows\System32 folder.  I deleted it and et voila.  How it got there is anybody's guess.